# My wordpress site suddenly displays this error for 2 days: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in ..../Module/ModuleViewAbstract.php

Tags: wordpress, syntax-error

My wordpress site suddenly displays this error for 2 days: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' on line 5 of this code :

```
protected function random_ads_position( $count ) {
    $position = - 1;
    $attr     = $this->attribute;
    if ( isset( $attr['ads_type'] ) && $attr['ads_type'] !== 'disable' ) {
        $position = $attr['ads_random'] ? rand( $attr['ads_position']['size'] ?? $attr['ads_position'], ( $count - 2 ) ) : $position = $attr['ads_position'];
    }

    if ( is_array( $position ) && isset( $position['size'] ) ) { /* check ads position for Elementor */
        $position = $position['size'];
    }

    return (int) $position;
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you write

```
 $position = $attr['ads_random'] ? rand( $attr['ads_position']['size'] ?? $attr['ads_position'], ( $count - 2 ) ) : $position = $attr['ads_position'];
```

Seems the problem is in this line of code.

Thank you